# Action cable to a specific div

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to update a specific div that can change depending on the stream.id.

I have the following :

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast('webconferencier_channel', participants_html: participants_html, stream_id: webconferencier.stream_id)
```

Where I do pass the `stream_id`.

I am looking to retrieve it in coffee file like this:

```
    received: (data) ->
  # Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
      participantsHtml = data.participants_html
      $('#show_participants' + data.stream_id).html(participantsHtml);
```

And then update the view as:

```
<div id="show_participants_#{<%= @stream.id %>}">
</div>
```

I can see the AC sending the div template with the other variables, but i cannot seem to retrieve and update it. I think my coffee syntax is incorrect.

In the view, the div id show up as :

```
<div id="show_participants_#{67089dbd-9826-41f2-97bc-b774b667ef66}">
</div>
```

with the UUID being the exact same string that i am passing through the coffee file. 
Does anyone know how i could make this work please?
Thank you

Comment: Try to remove curly braces and octothorp from div's `id` like `show_participants_UUID`. You can add `console.log` to the coffee to see what's happening inside.

Comment: It works perftectly. Later I will find a more secure way of sending the stream to a specific user. But I will use that technique for now. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove curly braces and octothorp from div's `id` like `show_participants_UUID`.

You can add console.log to the coffee to see what's happening inside.